# SVN synchronize an uncomitted project with the repository

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have a project say `Project` in my eclipse `workspace` which I commit on an svn repository. When I make some changes in my local copy, I can easily integrate those changes with the `project`->`right click` -> `team` -> `synchronize with the repository` option. But in case I have another project name `Project` **(same name for both projects)** in another workspace say `workspace2` which is not connected to `svn` and I want to synchronize it with the same project on `svn` repository **How should I do it?** Because the only choice in this case is `project`->`right click`->`team` -> `share project` or `apply patch`. To share this project I will have to `commit` it but in this case the contents of the project already available on `svn` repository will be lost. **I want to `merge` the two projects such that the useful content of both is merged and the merged copy is available on the `svn` repository. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

SVN can't automatically merge a SVN project with one that wasn't originally checked out from SVN. To merge two branches of a project, SVN needs to know which branch each change was made on. Otherwise it will just see the differences between the two sides, but won't have any way to know which side to keep. It can only do this if it has the history of each side's changes, which in this case you don't have.

What I would do is just diff the two projects, look at each change yourself, and decide whether to copy it into the SVN project. Start by backing up the non-SVN project, and committing any changes to the SVN project, so you have a clean place to revert to if you mess up. Then select both projects and do Compare With > Each Other. It will show you all the files that are different. Double-click each file to see the differences within the file, and copy them to the SVN side if you want to keep them. Then if everything looks good, you can commit it, and get rid of the non-SVN version.